# SortedSearch.countNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4) should return 2 because there are two array elements less than 4

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Need more efficient way

**Following are the results:**

- Example case: Correct answer
- Various small arrays: Correct answer
- Performance test when sortedArray contains ***lessThan***: Time
  limit exceeded
- Performance test when sortedArray doesn't contain ***lessThan***: Time limit exceeded

**Following is the code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortedSearch {
    public static int countNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan) {

        Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
        int count =0;

        for(int num :sortedArray){

            if(num < lessThan)
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SortedSearch.countNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4));
    }
}
```

Ref Link : [Try here](https://www.testdome.com/questions/java/sorted-search/9879?visibility=1&skillId=4)

Comment: Look up "Binary search"

Comment: place `System.out.println(count)` inside of your for-loop.
I suspect your loop isn't implemented properly. Youll be able to see how many times your loop is running.

Comment: Why would you sort a sorted array??

Answer (score 3):

Try below code

```
public static int countNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = sortedArray.length - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    while (start <= end) {
        mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (sortedArray[mid] < lessThan) {
            if (mid < sortedArray.length - 1 && sortedArray[mid + 1] < lessThan) { // check id next value is also valid
                start = mid + 1;
                continue;
            } else
                return mid + 1;
        }

        if (sortedArray[mid] >= lessThan) {
            end = mid - 1;
        } else {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

no need sort,only foreach,it is more effiective method

Comment: added for-each but still same result; check the code above

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's built-in binary search:

```
public static int countNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan) {
    int i = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(sortedArray, lessThan);
    if (i < 0) {
        return -i - 1;
    } else {
        // in case of duplicates, find first occurrence
        for (; i > 0 && sortedArray[i - 1] == lessThan; i--);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@shmosel Code is correct, but the for loop isn't needed. The binarySearch method returns the index of the value you are looking for. Therefore you'll only need to return i.

```
public static int countNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan) {
    int i = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(sortedArray, lessThan);
    if (i < 0) 
        return -i - 1;
    else
        return i;
}
```

Comment: [*If the array contains multiple elements with the specified value, there is no guarantee which one will be found.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-)

Answer (score 1):

They expect you to use the [Array.BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get 100%.

```
using System;

public class SortedSearch
    {
    public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
    {
        int lengthOfArray = sortedArray.Length;
        if (lengthOfArray == 0) return 0;

        if (sortedArray[0] >= lessThan) return 0;

        if (sortedArray[lengthOfArray - 1] < lessThan) return lengthOfArray;

        int index = Array.BinarySearch(sortedArray, lessThan);
        if (index < 0)
            return ~index;

        return index;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SortedSearch {
    public static int countNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan) {
           int end = sortedArray.length-1;
        int start = 0;
        int mid =0;

        while (start<=end){
            mid = (start+end)/2;
            if(sortedArray[mid] <lessThan){
                if(mid<sortedArray.length-1 && sortedArray[mid+1]<lessThan){
                  start = mid+1;
                  continue;
                }else{
                    return mid+1;
                }
            }else{
                end = mid-1;
            }

        }
return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class SortedSearch
 {
public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException("Waiting to be implemented.");
    int left=0;
    int right= sortedArray.Length-1;
    int mid=0;
    
    if(sortedArray[left]==lessThan)
       return 0;
    if(sortedArray[right]==lessThan)
      return right;
    if(sortedArray[right]<lessThan)
        return right+1;
    
    while(left<=right){
     
            mid=(right+left)/2;
        
        if(sortedArray[mid]==lessThan)
            return mid;
            
        if(sortedArray[mid]>lessThan){
            right=mid-1;
            
        }else{
            //Console.WriteLine(mid);
            //if(sortedArray[mid+1]==lessThan)
             //   return mid+1;
            if(sortedArray[mid+1]>=lessThan)
              return mid+1;
            else 
                left=mid+1;
        }
    }
   return 0;
   
}

 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { -1,1,7 }
                                                , 9));
}
```

}

Using the idea of binary search will solve the problem in O(logn) which means the complexity is reduced to half of the normal search using a loop to iterate all the element to find the solution with complexity of O(n), this was solved in C# but it can be translated to any programming language

Comment: The code is written in C#

Comment: Please elaborate your answer a little: How and why does it work? What is different from other answers. Also, please try to answer in the programming language asked for, even if this is very similar.

Comment: Using the idea of binary search will solve the problem in O(logn) which means the complexity is reduced to half of the normal search using a loop to iterate all the element to find the solution  with complexity of O(n), the question did not specify a language so I solved it in C# but it can be translated to any programming language

Comment: Thank you @israa alsasour. :) But what I meant was, please do so in your answer itself (edit it), so that other people with the same problem or the original author can easily see the difference.